# Ethernet questions

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Had my ethernet cable redone since the people that wired the house didn’t do it correctly and caused it to have interference. Bought a tester and shows it “passed”. (1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8)
/(3-6-1-4-5-2-7-8) is what I get. I’m getting speeds of 800+ on my ps5 as well as on my pc. Issue I’m having is whenever I play I lag. My ping bounces from 15-65. I used t-568b and didn’t mess with the other side that’s wired to a Keystone jack. Would that cause my ethernet connecting to have drops ?

Comment: First of all, your ping to where exactly? The game server? That's a long distance and many different links. If you suspect the cable, try local tests first, e.g. ping the local router, test iperf3 between two local wired computers, see if there's a tool that can measure packet loss.

Comment: First step is to verify that you indeed have dropped packets that cause the lag. Your OS (whatever it is) can show that information.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not your problem.  If ethernet cable works  it works - if you had terminated it problematically it would not pass data at above 100 megabit speeds at all.

What I believe you have done is created a crossover connection - so t568a on one side and b on the other.  This is not ideal, but as gigabit devices autonegotiate, its not a problem here.

Your latency issues could be a myriad of places.  Id use winmtr or similar to see where latency/packet loss is creeping in as the next step.  Its not foolproof, but it is often highly suggestive of where issues lie.

Comment: I completely missed that. Sorry